# Is there any official hair dagger or spike weapon, using long hair as a whip?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, stealth, content-identification

Is there any official (WotC, Dungeon, Dragon, Official websites, etc., ) weapon that is a dagger or spike used in the hair as a whip-style weapon?

This shows up as a surprise hidden weapon in some wuxia stories and shows.

I am confident that I have seen this sort of weapon somewhere in 3rd, or possibly d20 Modern, but I can't recall where exactly. Maybe some of the Rokugan stuff, or possibly Mahasarpa?

Comment: Related meta: [Are “Does this type of product exist” questions acceptable?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6052/are-does-this-type-of-product-exist-questions-acceptable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Dungeon* vol. 120 has the braid blade, an exotic weapon that allows a proficient user to tie it into their hair and make an extra attack with it at −5 during any full-attack. By “extra” I mean over and above iteratives, two-weapon fighting, *haste*, etc. That property makes it quite good, and fairly well worth the Exotic Weapon Proficiency feat.

Note that the article fails to give braid blades any kind of limit. As written, you can tie as many of them as you like into your hair, and then make that many attacks. For the sake of your game, I strongly recommend limiting that to one (whether officially, as DM, or unofficially, as a player just not buying more than one).

I am reasonably certain this is the only such weapon in D&D 3.5e.

Comment: The braid blade is the only one… for humans. While not a knife, the exotic weapon **snake chain** "is woven through a medusa’s snakes, allowing her to make melee attacks with a reach weapon in addition to using her gaze attack or shortbow. A snake chain is a reach weapon. A medusa can strike  opponents 10 feet away with the chain. In addition, unlike most other weapons with reach, she can use it against an adjacent foe" (*Savage Species* 46). (The description continues.) Unfortunately, there's no illustration of a medusa employing a snake chain, so I've no idea how it actually works.

Comment: @HeyICanChan My headcannon is that it is a chain made out of snakes.  KRyan - to be fair, encumbrance is a kind of limit.

Comment: @Yakk was "headcannon" a pun?

Comment: @MrHiTech  Laugh.  Misspelled Headcanon.

Comment: I wonder if a dwarf could tie one of those to their beard. Maybe a beard-axe. Hm...

Comment: Would a warshaper be able to duplicate a medusa's snakes?

Comment: @nijineko I think the answer is yes (but remember that morphic weapons is notoriously under-defined). But strictly speaking, I don’t think it doesn’t helps you: *Savage Species* specifies that the ability to use the snake chain is granted to “a medusa,” rather than saying it’s a property of snake hair or something. So strictly speaking, you have to “be” a medusa in order to use it. Which is something a lot of warshapers may well be able to do, but the class doesn’t grant that ability.

Comment: @HeyICanChan To me, that comment is a fine answer in and of itself, but should I take from your lack of answer that you’d prefer I just add it to mine?

Comment: Feel free to add it, but bear in mind that It doesn't strictly meet the question's criteria (which is why I didn't make it a standalone answer).